# git mv in VSCode does not update typescript / javascript import paths

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, git, visual-studio-code

I want to move a typescript file in VSCode such that:

1. Git acknowledges the file continuity.
2. VSCode updates the parent files' import statements.

I can achieve either, but not both.

**Using git mv:** VSCode doesn't update the parent files' import statements.

**Using manual drag & drop:** git regards this as a new file.

How can I do both?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can VS Code automatically update JavaScript and TypeScript import paths on file rename/move?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43542247/can-vs-code-automatically-update-javascript-and-typescript-import-paths-on-file)

Comment: @SwissCodeMen no, git regards this as a new file - i.e. as though i deleted the file and created a new one.

Comment: Wait, nvm - it turns out git doesnt actually track file renames anyways, even when git status shows renamed: someFileName.ts -> newFileName.ts

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VS Code 'git mv' to preserve file history?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63256354/vs-code-git-mv-to-preserve-file-history)

Answer (score 2):

After doing more [research](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16711026/18649771), it turns out ***git does not actually track file renames***.

Compare:

After using `git mv`, your `git status` will return something like:

```
renamed: someFileName.ts -> newFileName.ts
```

After using `mv`, your `git status` will return something like:

```
deleted:    someFileName.ts
untracked:  newFileName.ts
```

^**despite the apparent acknowledgement of a rename, git handles both scenarios identically.**

After running `git add -- someFileName.ts newFileName.ts`, you will get the same:

```
renamed: someFileName.ts -> newFileName.ts
```

Interestingly, this is not the norm for most SCMs. Linus explains the design decision [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20160304045715/http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/217).

So to answer the original question:
Use the VSCode integrated file explorer for file moves/renames - this updates import paths AND there is no detriment to version control.

Comment: Are you sure? What happens if you do `git log newFileName.ts` in each case?

Comment: @bruceg: yes,git does not keep track of renames. It also has guessing rules to detect renamings after the facts -- namely: if two files have enough lines in common, some commands in git will treat this as a rename. For example : `git log newFileName.ts` will stop at the first commit, but `git log --follow newFileName.ts` will also follow the history of `someFileName.ts`.

Comment: `git mv old new` is just a shortcut for `git rm --cached old; mv old new; git add new` (it is a bit more elaborate because it also preserves "staged content" and "worktree content", but that's the gist of it)

Comment: @LeGEC Excellent point. Yes. The git log --follow usually works to show the history of renamed files.

Comment: how do I bulk move mutliple source files from one directory as a github rename (not a delete and created file) AND have imports in all my source files updated?  Right now I move them using VSCode's file explorer, selecting update imports on the prompt. I then move the files back (this time not accepting the prompt), and then I git mv them so it is tracked a rename.