# How to rename and move a file in git with vscode

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, file-rename, file-move

I been trying to use git in vscode and I wanna know how is the way to rename or move a file successfully, for example when I try to rename a file, git notify me that the old file was deleted and now the new-renamed is untracked.

Comment: There is an existing question for this (even though none of the answers are great at the moment): [VS Code 'git mv' to preserve file history?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63256354/vs-code-git-mv-to-preserve-file-history)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you rename or move a file outside of Git (for example, using the file explorer in VSCode), Git recognizes it as a deletion of the old file and an addition of a new, untracked file. However, you can use Git commands to tell Git about the rename or move so that it tracks the changes correctly. Here's how you can do it using the command line or the integrated terminal in VSCode:

##### Using Git Command Line:

- Open a terminal in the directory of your Git repository.
- Use the following command to stage the rename: `git mv old_filename new_filename`

> Replace **old_filename** with the current name of the file and **new_filename** with the desired new name.

- If you run `git status` you will see a similar output:

```
renamed:    a.txt -> c.txt
```

- Commit the changes: `git commit -m "Rename file"`

```
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 rename a.txt => b.txt (100%)
```

Comment: there is a way to rename or move a file without a command?

Comment: You can do it through the VSCode interface itself, but then Git will still understand that you deleted one file and created another. But the way I've taught, just from the command line, isn't available in VSCode, well at least not natively, maybe with an extension...
And being honest, this flow of understanding that you've deleted a file and created another isn't a problem, it's something that occurs in all Git repositories, so you can rename from the interface and commit the changes without any problems.